# In the same stack value need to add a rectangle with text value and need to bring link to the end of stack

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am struggling to add the below requirement in my code:

- Need to add a rectangle in the same stack (attached image for reference).
- Need to bring down "Google link" just to the end of each stack.

But whenever I am doing so it is hampering all the alignment and not working.

For rectangle I have defined a .rectangle class in CSS and used inside my HTML body.

For "Google link" to print at the end of the stack I have used `span`.

Also, it would be helpful if I can get any better resources where I can design my web page and take export into HTML and CSS as I am new to this world so not sure about the resources available.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* Align to the left */
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Add margin between label-value pairs */
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* Add margin between label and input */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Add margin between text boxes */
}

.double-column {
  grid-column: span 2;
}


/* Add styles for the container with a scrollbar */

.scroll-container {
  max-height: 500px;
  /* Set the maximum height as needed */
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* Add margin at the top of the scrollable container */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Ensure content stacks vertically */
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* Align content to the left */
  width: 20%;
  /* Set the desired width */
  margin-left: 0;
  /* Reset the default margin */
}

.scroll-container p {
  margin: 0;
  /* Remove default margin on paragraphs */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* Add border between values */
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  /* Adjust padding as needed */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* Enable flexbox for alignment */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Align items to the right */
  align-items: center;
  /* Center items vertically */
}

.checkbox {
  order: 1;
  /* Adjust spacing between checkbox and text */
}


/* Additional style for the rectangle */

.rectangle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  /* Set the desired background color */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* Move the rectangle to the right */
  margin-top: -15px;
  /* Adjust the margin to position it at the top right */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="field1">field1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field1" value="Non-Editable Value 1" readonly>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="field2">field2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field2" value="Non-Editable Value 2" readonly>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="field3">field3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field3" value="Non-Editable Value 3" readonly>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="field4">field4:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field4" value="Non-Editable Value 4" readonly>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="field5">field5:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field5" value="Non-Editable Value 5" readonly>
  </div>

  <!-- Add any other form elements or buttons as needed -->

</form>
<!-- Title "Details" -->
<h2 class="details-title">Article Details</h2>
<!-- Container with scrollbar -->
<div class="scroll-container">
  <!-- Add more content to demonstrate the scrollbar -->
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> India India India India India India India India India
    <span class="google-link">
                <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
            </span>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Pakistan</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">India</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Australia</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Pakistan</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">India</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Australia</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Pakistan</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">India</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Australia</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Pakistan</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">India</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Australia</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Pakistan</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">India</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Australia</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Pakistan</p>

  <p>More content...</p>
</div>
```

[image: Image for reference]